# OpenXml: What is the difference between SdtBlock and SdtCell?

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

`SdtCell` and `SdtBlock` in `OpenXml.Wordprocessing` both serialize into `<w:sdt>` so what is the difference? I assume one is a table cell, which is what the Microsoft documentation appears to imply. The details provided are sparse at best, please clarify.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the MSDN pages for [sdtcell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.sdtcell.aspx) and [sdtblock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.sdtblock.aspx), *emphasis mine below*

The main difference is what type of content `<w:sdtContent>` you will have within the `<w:sdt>`

**SDTCELL**

This element specifies the presence of a structured document tag **around a single table cell**. The two child elements of this element shall be used to specify the properties and content of the current structured document tag via the sdtPr and sdtContent elements, respectively.

[Example: Consider a structured document tag with the friendly name company that must be located around a single table cell in a WordprocessingML document. This requirement would be specified as follows in the WordprocessingML:

```xml
<w:tr>
  <w:sdt>
    <w:sdtPr>
      <w:alias w:val="company"/>
    </w:sdtPr>
    <w:sdtContent>
      <w:tc>
      …
      </w:tc>
    </w:sdtContent>
  </w:sdt>
  …
</w:tr>
```

The sdt element specifies the structured document tag, the child sdtPr element contains the friendly name property set to company, **and the sdtContent element contains a single table cell (it is a cell-level structured document tag)**.

**SDTBLOCK**

This element specifies the presence of a **structured document tag around one or more block-level structures (paragraphs, tables, etc.)**. The two child elements of this element shall be used to specify the properties and content of the current structured document tag via the sdtPr and sdtContent elements, respectively.

[Example: Consider a structured document tag with the friendly name address that must be located around a single paragraph in a WordprocessingML document. This requirement would be specified as follows in the WordprocessingML:

```xml
<w:body>
  <w:sdt>
    <w:sdtPr>
      <w:alias w:val="address"/>
    </w:sdtPr>
    <w:sdtContent>
      <w:p>
      …
      </w:p>
    </w:sdtContent>
  </w:sdt>
  …
</w:body>
```

The sdt element specifies the structured document tag, the child sdtPr element contains the friendly name property set to address, **and the sdtContent element contains a single paragraph (it is a block-level structured document tag)**.

Comment: So if I'm understand this correctly, you would only use a sdtcell in the event that you wanted to tag a single cell in an existing table?